# regex to find domain without those instances being part of subdomain.domain

Tags: regex

I'm new to regex. I need to find instances of `example.com` in an `.SQL` file in Notepad++ **without those instances being part of** `subdomain.example.com`**(edited)**

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/406408/667903), I've tried using `^((?!subdomain))\.example\.com$`, but this does not work.

I tested this in Notepad++ and @ https://regex101.com/r/kS1nQ4/1 but it doesn't work.

Help appreciated.

Comment: Can you give an example of a matching URL as well as one which does not match?  Maybe you could write a regex which matches positives rather than excluding negatives.

Comment: Why not to use simple `^example\.com$`?

Comment: this could be it `[^\.]+(?=\.[a-z\.]{2,6}\b)`

Comment: Ahh. Thanks @GiorgiNakeuri. This doesn't work in Notepad++ though, which is supposed to be [using the standard PCRE (Perl) syntax](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions),

Comment: If you really need the matches to be flush left, all you need is `^example\.com$` which matches lines with nothing else on them.  If not, please clarify how the `^` factors in, and/or maybe show a real snippet of text from which you need the matches to be extracted.

Comment: @tripleee, the matches are not on one line with nothing else on them, they are interspersed randomly through a PHPmyAdmin `.sql` dump.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without access to example text, it's a bit hard to guess what you really need, but the regular expression

```
(^|\s)example\.com\>
```

will find `example.com` where it is preceded by nothing or by whitespace, and followed by a word boundary.  (You could still get a false match on `example.com.pk` because the period is a word boundary.  Provide better examples in your question if you want better answers.)

If you specifically want to use a lookaround, the neative lookahead you used (as the name implies) specifies what the regex should not match at this point.  So `(?!subdomain\.)example` trivially matches always, because `example` is not `subdomain.` -- the negative lookahead can't not be true.

You might be better served by a lookbehind:

```
(?<!subdomain\.)example\.com
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/kS1nQ4/3

Answer (score 1):

Simple

```
^example\.com$
```

with `g,m,i` switches will work for you.

https://regex101.com/r/sJ5fE9/1

If the matching should be done somewhere in the middle of the string you can use negative look behind to check that there is no dot before:

```
(?<!\.)example\.com
```

https://regex101.com/r/sJ5fE9/2

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that takes into account the protocols/prefixes,

```
/^(www\.)?(http:\/\/www\.)?(https:\/\/www\.)?example\.com$/
```